# Unable to find explicit activity class have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to open next activity but having following error

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.example.pc.lovequoteandcalculator/int}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

My Manifest.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.pc.lovequoteandcalculator">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".lovecalculate" />
    <activity android:name=".quoteforlove" />
    <activity android:name=".quotestoimpress"></activity>
</application>
```

And this is how I am starting new activity

```
val btn = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnlovecal) as Button btn.setOnClickListener { 
    startActivity(
            Intent(this@MainActivity,activity_lovecalculate::class.java)
        ) 
}
```

Can someone point out what am I missing here?

Comment: * <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: There is a problem in how you are constructing the `Intent`. You may wish to edit your question and post the code where you are creating the `Intent` and calling `startActivity`.

Comment: val btn = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnlovecal) as Button
        btn.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity,activity_lovecalculate::class.java)) }

Comment: thats how i am calling intent activity in main

Answer (score 1):

You seem to calling the wrong activity with the following:

```
 Intent(this@MainActivity,activity_lovecalculate::class.java)
```

which is trying to call `activity_lovecalculate` activity. But you only have:

```
<activity android:name=".lovecalculate" />
```

So, try using `lovecalculate` with something like this:

```
val btn = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnlovecal) as Button btn.setOnClickListener { 
    startActivity(
            Intent(this@MainActivity, lovecalculate::class.java)
        ) 
}
```

---

P.S: Please use a correct coding style for class name.